# Div show/hide media query

Tags: mobile, media

What code can I use to make a particular div show only if on a mobile width?

I have a 100% width full div at the top of my screen, would like it to only show when the device is specified as a mobile width.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I'm not sure, what you mean as the 'mobile width'. But in each case, the CSS  `@media` can be used for hiding elements in the screen width basis. See some example:

```html
<div id="my-content"></div>
```

...and:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #my-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #my-content { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}
```

Some truly mobile detection is kind of hard programming and rather difficult. Eventually see the: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ or other similar sources.

Comment: This worked for me ONLY when I changed the id to a class (everything else the same). Might have to do something with my WP theme. Either way,  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be wanting to access the viewport of the device. You can do this by inserting this meta tag in your header.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: I forgot to add this, for an hour I am circulating over almost all  answers :))

Answer (score 1):

```
 Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  #my-content{
   width:100%;
 }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  #my-content{
   width:100%;
 }
 }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
display: none;
 }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
// Havent code only get for more informations 
 }
```