# DIV not showing on @media 414px

Tags: html, css

Hi can you guys help I am getting lost I don't know why my DIVs are not showing on on @media 414px but it's showing on 767px - 1920px. I did used scroll reveal.js I think that's the thing that affects my website. Please Help me. Thanks is advance

Here is the css below:

```
.products .prod4{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod5{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod6{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod7{
    display:none;
    }
    .products .prod8{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod9{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod10{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod12{
        display:none;
    }
    .products .prod13{
        display:none;
    }

    .products .prod14{
        display:none;
    }

    .products h2{
        margin-top:-10px;
        font-size:45px;
    }

    .products p{
        margin-left:-15px;
        margin-right:-55px;
        margin-top:-45px;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    .factory-caption-h1a1b span{
         font-size: 110px;
         margin-left:90px;
    }

    .products .resize-top{
        margin-top:-70px;
    }
    .products .blackbg2{
        height:350px;
        background: url(../img/blackbg.jpg) no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        margin-left:-0px;
        margin-bottom:200px;
    }

    .products .blackbg2 p{
        color:white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="my-content"></div>
```

...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #my-content { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #my-content { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}
```

**Please check this link:-[Div show/hide media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796297/div-show-hide-media-query)**