# do i show a div in Media-queries with display?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

### **Hey Stackoverflow!**

I have a problem.
I have already tried to look on other questions, but i didn't get the answer I want, so I'll ask here instead.

I am currently working in php (html, css help)

My problem is that I want to show 4 pictures in my media queries (480px) 
and hide them if the screen is more than (850px)

Do you know what I have to do?

Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 480px)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div show/hide media query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796297/div-show-hide-media-query)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 849px) {
        .picture{
           display:block;
        }
   }
   @media screen and (min-width: 850px)  {
        .picture{
           display:none;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a media query for 850px and mention `display:none` in the CSS.