# How to hide div when mobile

Tags: html, hide

I made an announcement div and I want it to disappear when I use the mobile version of the webpage because it occupy to much space when resized for the mobile version.
How can I hide a div when the size of the webpage becomes bigger?

for example: mobile web surfing

my code is

```css
body {margin:0;}

.icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0088B8;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bar a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #0073C4;
}

.active {
    background-color: #9b0a0a !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="./index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="./search.php"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href="./news.php"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="./search.php?search_id=unanswered"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: You can use media queries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div show/hide media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796297/div-show-hide-media-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe he is new to html and css...
Try to use css rules to achieve this, like Robert said media queries.
Put in your html head this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And in your css file wirte below your div-rules (lets say your div has the id="test"):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #test {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Now the div is hidden when the screen width is larger than e.g. 800px.

Comment: I have uploaded my code, can you help me now? I'm new to css

Comment: you want to hide the icon bar when the website becomes bigger?

Comment: yes. 'cause it's like a second menu https://prnt.sc/fl28lq EDIT: actually, nevermind I figured it out! Thanks!